# Image texture not showing on object that has UV Map?

Tags: mesh, uv, image

Following a tutorial, I'm trying to add a Texture to an object via the Texture menu instead of through Materials.
I have Unwrapped 2 different ways (Project From View, Unwrap). I have tried "Render preview" mode.

I'm very confused as to why it doesn't show up on my mesh (But on the Tutorial the image does show up at this point). I have attached screenshots to show my setup. Any ideas, please?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to create a material that contains the image and you need to be in shaded or rendered viewport mode.

Comment: are you sure the material thing is necessary? That's how I'm used to doing textures but this tutorial had the guy only using the Image Texture menu and it worked (maybe he left stuff out). What is the point of "Image Texture" menu then? Edit: Yeah, I think he just didn't show the material process. Thank you, that explains so much.

Comment: The last time you were able to show Textures that did not belong to a material was Blender Internal Renderer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what the tutorial left out was, that before painting on your target, you have to assign the *resulting* (at first probably blank) texture to a material and then switch into a view that supports textured display. 
Either solid with textures enabled, Material Preview or Render Preview.

The Texture Properties are supposed to set the image properties *before* it is used as a brush. It does not effect the resulting texture directly.

Back in Blender 2.7x and before you could assign textures to UVs without using materials. That only worked with BI and could be pretty confusing, so they removed the functionality. 
If you have the node wrangler addon enabled, you can have your material nodes open somewhere and CTRL SHIFT click on a texture node to preview it in the viewport.